# Hyperparameter tuning job In Sagemaker with cross valdiation

Tags: python, cross-validation, amazon-sagemaker, hyperparameters

I managed to get something [along those lines](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/automatic-model-tuning-ex-tuning-job.html) to work. This is great but to be more on the save side (i.e. not rely too much on the train validation split) one should really use cross validation. I am curious, if this can also be achieved via Sagemaker hyperparameter tuning jobs? I googled extensively ...

Comment: How does HP tuning relate to cross validation? You could do cross validation without HP tuning, or vise versa. Cross validation has to do with the algorithm you use. Are you attempting to control cross validation properties using hyperparameters?

Comment: Emmm - I beg to differ - the fold average guides the search ....

Comment: to add to this - espeically for small number of observations just using e.g. a vlaidation set could be very very wrong - I hope that clarifies this!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible through HPO.

You need to add additional step in your workflow to achieve cross-validation.

Comment: thanks - have you seen any blogs - googled a lot and it is difficult to follow the scattered doc ... guess I have to use script mode etc. I have to say quite disappointing that something so fundamental is not possible OOTB.